# NDK is looking into wrong directory

Tags: android, android-ndk, library-project

I am using the awesome library `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever`. This library requires me to add some platform specific native libraries.
For convenience I have a library project with all the code and a separate project for the free and the paid version of my app.
The package name of the library project is `com.vidanalysis`, the paid version has got the same name and the free version's name is `com.vidanalysis.free`. The `FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever` library is included in the library project.
The paid version is working fine, but the problem is that the free version is trying to find the library in `com.vidanalyis`, which doesn't exist when you haven't installed the paid version.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If it is only one native library why not just include the different library files in the two projects, and remove the dependency to the library project?

Comment: Then I need to have the jar also in these two projects. But I need it in the library project!

Comment: I developed this library, have you tried adding the prebuilt native libs (and fmmr.jar) to both project's "libs" folder?

Comment: After reading even further, the behavior you describe is normal. When loading the native .so files Android will check /data/data/<packagename> for the libraries. Your library, since it has the same package name as the free version, installs them to the correct location. The solution (as described in the project README) is to add the prebuilt-libs and fmmr.jar into each project's (paid and free) "libs" folder.

Comment: As you said, Android checks /data/data/<packagename> for the libraries. The library is only used in the library project with package name com.vidanalysis. So it tries to load it from this location. Adding both the jar and this libs in paid and free version didn't help here.

Comment: You aren't understanding, just because you only use that code within the library project doesn't matter. The native libraries are installed to /data/data/<packagename> where "packagename" is the name of the application package NOT the library package.